# Showing last item in ListView Using XML Parsing

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing, listviewitem

I want to show list of cities in ListView Using XML parsing I am getting response in Logcat but In ListView, there is showing only last item, i many tried for solve this but I am stuck in it.
Please help to solve this

My XML Parsing code looks like below

```
class XmlPullParserHandler {
    private List<City> cityArrayList = new ArrayList<City>();
    private City cities;
    private String text;

    public List<City> getCitiess() {
        return cities;
    }

    public List<City> parse(InputStream is) {
        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("city")) {
                            // create a new instance of cities
                            cities = new City();
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Area")) {
                            // add cities object to list
                            cityArrayList.add(cities);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("AreaName") {
                            cities.setAreaName(text);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CityCode")) {
                            cities.setCityCode(text);
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("AreaCode")) {
                            cities.setAreaCode(text);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cityArrayList;
    }
}
```

Set adapter code is below

```
List<City> cities = null;
        try {
            XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("cityapi/citylist.xml");
            cities = parser.parse(is);

            AdapterSearchCity adapter = new AdapterSearchCity(ActivityCitySearch.this, cities);
            searchListview.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My xml is like below

```
<city>
<Area>
<AreaName>L.A</AreaName>
<CityCode>ABC</CityCode>
<AreaCode>XYZ</AreaCode>
</Area>
</city>
```

I am not getting where I am wrong Please help me

Comment: Did u debug? What is the size of cityArrayList?

Comment: Yeah I debug...

Comment: What is the size of cities arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution where i was wrong

I put **"city"** instead of **"Area"**

It should be like this.

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Area")) {
                            // create a new instance of cities
                            cities = new City();
                        }
                        break;
```